# Ключевое слово для обозначения чистых функций

Tags: c, gcc, clang

В википедии читал о чистых функциях и наткнулся на эту фразу:

> Некоторые компиляторы, такие как *gcc*, в целях оптимизации
>   предоставляют программисту ключевые слова для обозначения чистых
>   функций.

Никогда про это не слышал. Нигде в Интернете не нашел это ключевое слово. Может, кто знает? Если такое слово есть, то подскажите его же, но только для `clang`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int output2(int x) __attribute__((pure));

int output2(int x)
{
  return x+1;
}
```